# How can I render my fetched data without using tables to format it?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

So I am trying to align my fetched JSON data.

What I need is to have data aligned with each attribute title without using a table like in the image below.

With a table I can do it, but without I can't seem to find a way.

[image]

My table example:

```
export default function UserDetails({ data }) {

 const classes = useStyles()

   return (
    <div>
      <h1>User Details</h1>
      <Table size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">description</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">email</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">group</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">sn</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">uid</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow>
            {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value])=> (
              <TableCell align="left" key={key}> {value}</TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>


    </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to render a table without tables? Looks like the semantic thing to do.

Comment: Also, if you insist on not using a table, if you break down a table into its cells, then treat them not as cells but just as individual elements on a page, I'm sure (with some very simple CSS) you can figure out how to render the data in an apparent table-like format. Though like @FedericoklezCulloca said, if it's a table of data, just render it as a table

Comment: I agree with @FedericoklezCulloca, however if you still think you don't want to use table, build your own one with flexbox, just google 'flexbox tables'

Comment: You can do it with css's display table and table cell properties, but that would require much more code then just simply using html table

Answer (score 1):

I found that i can use `ListItem` with `@material-ui`to achieve the same result.
This was what i was looking for. With some css i could make it display the items in the horizontal.

Here is the code:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem"
import List from "@material-ui/core/List"
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText"
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider"

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display  : "flex",
    alignItems : "center",

  },
}))

export default function UserDetails({ data }) {

 const classes = useStyles()

   return (

    <div >
      <h1>User Details</h1>
        <List className={classes.root}>
            <ListItem > Cn </ListItem>
            <ListItem > Description</ListItem>
            <ListItem > Mail </ListItem>
            <ListItem > Ou </ListItem>
            <ListItem > Sn </ListItem>
            <ListItem > Uid </ListItem>
        </List>
    <Divider />
        <List className={classes.root}>
            {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value])=> (
            <ListItem align = "left ">{value} </ListItem>
             ))}
        </List>
    </div>
   )
}
```